# Implication between two weak formulations

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open bounded set, $Q_T:=\Omega \times (0,T)$ and $f \in L^2(Q_T)$. Suppose that

$$(a)\;\; \int_{Q_T} \partial_t u \;\phi+\int_{Q_T} \nabla u \; . \nabla \phi = \int_{Q_T} f  \phi \;\; \forall \phi \in L^2(0,T;W^{1,\infty}(\Omega))$$
where $\partial_t u \in L^2(0,T;{W^{1,\infty}}(\Omega)^*)$

Prove that  $ \forall \phi \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega))$

$$ (b) \;\;\;\int_{Q_T} \partial_t u \;\phi+\int_{Q_T} \nabla u \; . \nabla \phi = \int_{Q_T} f  \phi. \;\;$$

My attempt :

Let $\phi \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega))$, and consider
$$
A(\phi):=\begin{cases}
\phi \;\;\;\;\; \text{if}\;\;\; \vert \phi(x,t)\vert \leq  \Vert \phi\Vert_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\\
\Vert \phi \Vert_{L^\infty(\Omega)}  \;\;\;\;\;  \text{if}\;\;  \Vert \phi\Vert_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \leq \phi(x,t)\\
-\Vert \phi \Vert_{L^\infty(\Omega)}  \;\;\;\;\;  \text{if}\;\;  \phi(x,t) \leq  -\Vert \phi\Vert_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\\
\end{cases}
$$
then choosing $A(\phi)$ as a test function in $(a)$, we obtain $(b)$.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: No. Also the claim is wrong as stated: the product $\partial_t u \phi$ is not well-defined under the weaker assumptions on $\phi$.

Comment: @daw, If we neglect (b) for a moment and  choose A(ϕ) as a test function in (a) since $A(ϕ) \in L^2(0,T;W^{1,\infty}(Ω))$, the product $\partial_t u A(\phi)$ is well defined and we get exactly (b), right?

Comment: $A(\phi)$ does not belong to $L^2(W^{1,\infty})$.